# How can I replace section* with subsection?

Tags: floats, sectioning, formatting

Every time I try to use Latex commands with asterisks in them the compiler says

```
"Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete."
```

I want to define

```
\begingroup
\let\section*=\subsection
\endgroup
```

This is needed to replace all section* headers of `\listoffigures` and `\listofalgorithms`.

I'm using the article class.

Example code:

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0cm,bmargin=0cm,lmargin=0cm,rmargin=0cm}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\protect\caption{sdfdsfdfsdfdsfsd}


\end{algorithm}
\begingroup
\let\section*=\subsection

\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}


\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I've also tried doing it for listofalgorithms with

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listalgorithmname}{loa}
\endgroup}
```

but only this [image: Screenshot of the result] is the result.

Comment: Welcome! The answer is to figure out why you get errors when you use a command with an asterisk - not to try to hide one particular manifestation of the problem by burying it. However, since that is not normal behaviour, we need a Minimal non-Working Example which we can compile to reproduce the problem. Start with `\documentclass{article}` and finish with `\end{document}` make sure that your code gives the error you are reporting before you paste it here so that you can be sure we'll be able to reproduce it.

Comment: If you replace `\section*` with `\subsection` you would get toc entries with subsection counting by `\listoffigure`, `\tableofcontents`, `\theindex`, `\thebibliography` etc. As cfr stated: There must be (severe) errors...

Comment: I've updated my post to include an example where I get the same error and an alternative which doesn't work correctly either.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I created this post only because that one line doesn't work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just want to set "List of Algorithms" to be a subsection header instead of a section* header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the errors is that `\section*` is not really a command in its own right.  The command name is `\section` which calls `\@startsection` with first argument `section`.  One of the early things that `\@startsection` does is check to see whether the following input character is `*` or not: if it is `*` then `\@ssect` is called, otherwise it essentially runs `\@sect`.

You can gleam some of this information by issuing `\show\section*` in your document.  The `.log` file will then contain:

```
> \section=\long macro:
->\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }.
l.20 \show\section
                  *
```

The break in the final two lines between `\section` and `*` indicates that `*` is not part of the name.  For more details one can read `source2e.pdf`.

In any case, for changing the heading style of the list of algorithms or whatever, your suggested substitution is not the correct approach.  Christian Hupfer's answer points to the relevant macros, but you don't really need to use patching commands.   A simple redefinition of `\float@listhead` will do, either in the preamble to have global effect on all such lists, or in a local group enclosing the particular `\listof` command you wish to affect.  Here is the global version:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\float@listhead}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\label{sec:first-section}


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Substitute}
Replace \( x \) by \( y \).
\end{algorithm}

\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}

\end{document}
```

The corresponding redefinition for figures is:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\subsection{\listfigurename}\@starttoc{lof}}
\makeatother
```

Note both my redefinitions leave the handling of running heads up to the `\subsection` command.

Comment: Of course, redefinition would do, but it would use `\subsection` even in a `book` - like document. On the other hand, the O.P. has `article`, so this good as well!

Answer (score 6):

The `\section*` commands can be replaced with `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` package.

The easier command is `\listoffigures`, which uses `\section*` by default, but since `float` is used and `\listof` uses `\float@listhead`, the later command has to be patched too.

Here, all other floats would use `\section*` for the `\listof` command too.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0cm,bmargin=0cm,lmargin=0cm,rmargin=0cm}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatother

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{\section*}{\subsection}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\float@listhead}{\section*}{\subsection}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\begin{algorithm}
\protect\caption{sdfdsfdfsdfdsfsd}


\end{algorithm}


\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since there is no section, `\thesubsection` will yield `0.x` like - entries

Comment: This code works but as soon as I use it in the big project I get a few errors like

\listof{algorithm}{Algorithmenverzeichnis}                                               
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.

The line with float@listhead is the one causing the error.

Comment: `\def\section*{\subsection}` also seems to work, but is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Lorehead It produces the same error as ChristianHupfer's solution.

Comment: Well, yes, but I said that it’s probably not what he wants, didn’t I?

Comment: @Lorehead don't do that! it would redefine `\section` and make any use of section without a `*` into an error.

Comment: Okay.  Wasn’t going to try that myself, but good to know.

Comment: @StefanBerger: Well, either there's more you do in a bigger document which isn't shown here -- how can I help then? Perhaps it's something `LyX` does? I never have used LyX